# ODBC overflow on unsigned tinyint

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, odbc, unixodbc

I have an issue where unixODBC is not handling the upper-half numbers of an unsigned tinyint column. I'm able to "correct" this by increasing the size to an unsigned smallint. I'm wondering if there is any other solution to this problem. My understanding is that tinyint, as well as unsigned, are not standard SQL definitions, but I'm not sure if that is why unixODBC doesn't handle them.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (id TINYINT UNSIGNED);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.45 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES (126),(127),(128),(129);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|  126 |
|  127 |
|  128 |
|  129 |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is what I get from isql:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 126 |
| 127 |
| 1844|
| 1844|
+-----+
SQLRowCount returns 4
4 rows fetched
```

This is actually happening in two different environments (but with similar versions). And here are the versions:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

$ isql --version
unixODBC 2.3.9
```

Comment: What is `isql`?  (It sounds like you need to abandon it!)

Comment: @RickJames `isql, iusql - unixODBC command-line interactive SQL tool` This is just a tool proving my issue. I'm actually having a problem in my application in using the unixODBC library. So, the problem seems to actually be with the ODBC driver.

Comment: Have you tried using a custom ODBC driver for MySQL that handles unsigned tinyint correctly, such as the MySQL Connector/ODBC?

Comment: Also another option is to cast the unsigned tinyint to a larger data type, such as unsigned smallint, in your SQL query when using unixODBC. This way, you can avoid the overflow issue without changing the table structure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @Kozydot. CAST is probably a good solution, but it will take quite a bit of effort for me to modify my environment to use a custom query. As for the driver, I believe it does come from Connector. Is there another package that would have a different MySQL ODBC driver?

Comment: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/mysql/ https://www.devart.com/odbc/mysql/ https://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-odbc-driver-32-64-bit-/about/